# Does CPU Use Logic Gates?

Tags: logic

I'm not sure if I understand logic gates?  Are logic gates how the cpu makes calculations with binary data?  Or are they two entirely separate things?  If so, where do logic gates have relevance?

Answer (score 2):

Logic gates are the building blocks of digital hardware design.  I think of the following list in terms of more and more complex building blocks.  Each item is a building block that makes up the following items.

1. silicon and doping minerals
2. transistors (nmos, pmos, ...)
3. logic gates (inverters, AND/OR gates, buffers, ...)
4. combinational and sequential circuits (adders, flip-flops, muxes, ...)
5. ALUs, data paths, and memory elements
6. CPU
7. Motherboard
8. Computer
9. Machine code
10. Assembly code
11. compiled code
12. applications and database
13. systems and networks

Now, I just made that list up off-hand and it is surely missing some important elements.

The purpose of that listing was to illustrate that the *logic gates* you are asking about are the building blocks of all digital circuits, whether they be computational in nature or datapath-related.

A CPU is made up of many digital components, some of which are computational units like you are asking about.  The CPU takes *machine code*, which is just a string of binary data stored in memory, and it decodes that into specific instructions which tell it several things, such as where to retrieve input data, what kind of computation(s) to do, where to store output data.

For example, an instruction may be decoded as ADD r3, r1, r2, which in some languages could mean "add two binary numbers stored in registers *r1* and *r2* and then store the result in *r3*".
It is most definitely logic gates that the CPU is made up of which do the data loading, routing, computing, and storing.

I hope that answers your question.